# how to represent symmetric many to many relationship

Tags: database-design

suppose i have a entity called USER and a relationship FRIENDSHIP exist between two USERs
SO for that i have a table 'USER' and a relationship table 'FRIENDSHIP'

USER
id  firstName  LastName
1    taher     chhabrawala
2    john      Dsouza
3    rahul     singh
4    deepak    patel

Friendship
id    id
1     2
1     3
1     4
4     1
4     3

In the above table i am storing the same information twice i.e "taher is a friend of deepak and deepak is a friend of taher"

Is there any way to reduce this redundancy ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could certainly just assume that all friendships are symmetric and store that friendship only once, but that would mean that when you want to query for all of Taher's friends, you have to look for his ID in either column.

Alternately you could have a separate table of relationship ID's, and then a one-to-many table of relationship to user.  This has the advantage that it would allow multi-person relationships if someday you want that, and would let you add meta-data about the relationship (when it started, who suggested it, whatever).

```
   User                
Id    Name          
1     Taher         
2     Deepak        

Relationship              
Id     StartDate           
1      2010-08-23

UserRelationship
RelationshipId UserId
1                1
1                2
```

On the other hand, on Facebook, for example, I can "friend" someone and they can decide not to friend me back.  If you don't have the "redundant" approach that you're using now, how will you represent that not-yet-reciprocal friendship?

Comment: Cool 
I had never thought of multi-person scenario
But for two-person scenario i think this would be more suitable
RelationshipId| User1_Id | User2_Id 
what do you think?

And i really liked this approach, Thanks

Comment: If you put a User1 and User2 column in the same row, you're really back to the beginning: if you want to find all of Taher's friends, you have to look for every row that has Taher's ID as either User1 or as User2.

Answer (score 5):

Make up a rule like 'the first ID value is always lower than the second ID value,' so you can ensure there are no duplicates.

In that case, pair (4,1) is invalid, and pair (4,3) would be stored as (3,4).

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to store just 1 record per each pair of friends. However, it makes harder to maintain uniqueness; all queries for getting/updating/removing friend relationship become more complex compared to "redundant" solution. Also, the solution with 2 records allows you maintain friends requests (E.g., UserA asks UserB to be a friend. UserB can confirm or reject this request). So I'd say redundancy is perfectly valid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you did decide to use the symmetric design then it might be useful to ensure that every friendship is always bidirectional. You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Friendship
 (UserId1 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Users (UserId),
  UserId2 INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (UserId1, UserId2),
  FOREIGN KEY (UserId2, UserId1) REFERENCES Friendship (UserId1, UserId2));

INSERT INTO Friendship (UserId1, UserId2)
VALUES (1,2),(2,1);
```

Comment: Well, I like the idea. But you can't insert rows.

Comment: No, constraint is checked row by row.

innodb_version          | 5.7.24                  |
version                 | 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

INSERT INTO Friendship (UserId1, UserId2) VALUES (1,2),(2,1);

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tests`.`Friendship`, CONSTRAINT `Friendship_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId2`, `UserId1`) REFERENCES `Friendship` (`UserId1`, `UserId2`))

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares, Quite so. It works in most SQL DBMSs but not in MySQL. But that's true of a great many things and nobody asked for a MySQL-specific solution.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, I assumed it was MySql (because that was I was looking for). I'm really surprised it would work in any DBMS - but I'm clearly wrong : I tried it in sqlfiddle.com, it works indeed in (at least) PostgreSql 9.6 and Oracle (with SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2,1 FROM DUAL instead of multiple VALUES)

Answer (score 0):

If you store the two rows, you will be required to enforce an integrity rule that ensures that friendships always come in pairs.

Store only one row in the table (say, FR), and create a view SYMFR as

SELECT x,y FROM FR
UNION
SELECT x as y, y as x FROM FR