# SQL Select On Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm struggling to work out how to get this SELECT working in the way that I want.

I have a UserProfile table and a table of relationships between users.

```
UserProfile

Id              Name       IsPulic
----------------------------
1               Tom        1
2               Adam       1
3               Harry      0
4               Billy      0

Relationships

Id              UserId     RelationId   Confirmed
-------------------------------------------------
     1          1          2            1
     2          2          3            1
     3          3          4            1
```

I'm trying to get all of Adams friends (plus other data from other tables left out for brevity) but I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

```
SELECT 
    up.[Id],
    up.[DisplayName],
    up.[IsPublic]
FROM
    [UserProfile] up
    INNER JOIN [Relationships] rel1 ON rel1.UserId = up.[Id]
    INNER JOIN [Relationships] rel2 ON rel2.RelationId = up.[Id]
WHERE
    rel1.[UserId ] = 2 OR rel2.[RelationId] = 2
```

Most of the examples I've seen of this situation flips the tables around but then I'd have multiple references to get at the data I want from the UserProfile table.

What I want is a list of User that have a relationship with Adam (Id - 2) so that would yield a list of Harry (via RelationId foreign key) and Tom (via UserId foreign key).

Whats the best was of getting the right list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to represent symmetric many to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550093/how-to-represent-symmetric-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to double `JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [UserProfile] up
    INNER JOIN [Relationships] rel1 ON rel1.UserId = up.[Id] OR rel1.RelationId = up.[Id]
WHERE
     up.[Id] = 2
```

Comment: But that just gets two rows like `2 Adam 1`

Comment: If you want more data you can expand the selected fields change `SELECT up.[Id], up.[DisplayName], up.[IsPublic]` to `SELECT *` or whatever fits your needs. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    up.[Id],
    up.[DisplayName],
    up.[IsPublic]
FROM
    [UserProfile] up
    INNER JOIN [Relationships] rel1 ON rel1.UserId = up.[Id] OR rel1.RelationId = up.[Id]
WHERE
    (rel1.[UserId] = 2 OR rel1.[RelationId] = 2) AND up.[Id] <> 2
```