# Creating an n:m relationship between multiple rows of the same table

Tags: php, mysql

Generally I have the need to create n:m relationship between two tables and I use the following scheme:

e.g.

Accounts and Contacts have an n:m relationship so I add a Account2Contacts reference table with the id of both Account and Contact to be associated. Multiple rows of this table allow Accounts to be connected to multiple Contacts and Contacts to be associated with multiple Accounts.

That's great, but what about an n:m relationship between multiple rows of the same table? I foresee problems. Each row of the Account2Account table (id, from_id, to_id) will only describe the connection between accounts in one direction.

So if Account1 has id 10 and Account2 id 20 when adding the connection Account1->Account2 the insert will be

addLink(1, 10, 20) for example.

This connection implies Account2->Account1, but looking up the Account2 id in the 'from_id' field will not show the connection.

I have toyed with the idea of generating the reciprocal insert automatically (2, 20, 10), but I'm concerned about what happens in a three way relationship or more. I'll have to add all the permutations of connections such that any account in the group can find all it's relationships in one lookup against the 'from_id' field.

Is there a design paradigm for this type of relationship that I'm unaware of?

Comment: What does that mean _"three way relationship or more"_? Is your relationship somehow differ in this case than relationship between pairs? I.e. if `a1`, `a2` and `a3` are linked, then it's full graph (each with each) or it's just transitive connection? (so `a1<->a2<->a3`) ? Could you provide more specific about your structure - and especially about direction of your connections? (if it may be a case when `a1 -> a2` is true, but `a2->a1` is false)

Comment: In my case a1->a2 will always mean a2->a1 and additionally, a1->a2 and a1->a3 will also mean a2->a3. So you can see that each forward connection needs to imply the reverse as well as all indirect connections.

I want to able to supply any account id and have all the accounts to which it connected returned.

Comment: Then it depends of what purposes must fulfill the DB architecture. Because if you want just to store information - then ok, restore transitive dependency in application (so do not store additional rows). But if that's about search - then what is that search and what is it's goal

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am concerned about the fact that although I can discover a2->a3 and a3->a2 from the links between a1, and a2 and a3, it is dependant upon those relationships being intact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to represent symmetric many to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550093/how-to-represent-symmetric-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: I'd keep it simple: 1 relationship = 2 rows (a,b),(b,a)

Comment: @shudder, yes I was considering that, but when I additionally have (a,c) I want (c,a) but also (c,b) and (b,c). I've been looking into abl's response and I think there answer is there.

Comment: Ahh it's a "group schema" then. For me it would be additional `group` + `user_group` tables. Searching for this here will give you detailed answers as well.